# Flutter/Laravel - Options to store locally on device

Tags: mysql, laravel, flutter

I'm trying to make a centralized POS system, was wondering what are my options to save data locally to the device to save data connection rather than making the POS online-only app.

I already have the APIs from Laravel being pulled into JSON and basically need to find a way to store data, as well as to convert image_location into blob or something Flutter can do, (is Image.memory viable?). The APIs will only be triggered on app startup if the device is connected to the internet.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a plugin called sqflite which works for ios and android.
and also SharedPreference plugin which stores data in key-value format.
you can search for plugins and there example on https://pub.dev/